# How can i fix this method so it returns null if the car type is not found

Tags: java

How can i fix this method so it returns null if the car type is not found?
Im new to java so take it with a grain of salt

```
public static Car findCar (Car[] cars, String type) 
{ 
    if (cars.length == 0) 
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ("no cars"); 
 
    
    Car    cheapestCar = cars[0]; 
    double  price = cheapestCar.getPrice (); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) 
        if (cars[i].getPrice() < price && 
            cars[i].getType().equals(type)) 
        { 
            cheapestCar = cars[i]; 
            price = cheapestCar.getPrice (); 
            
        } 
    
    return cheapestCar;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `Car  cheapestCar = cars[0];` to `Car cheapestCar = null;`

Comment: The first car you are currently selecting isn't necessarily of the right type. You need to go through the array until you find the first car of the right type, and only then start looking at the price.

Comment: As a general note, throwing an exception when the array is empty is inconsistent with returning null if no cars of the right type are found: an empty array trivially means there are not cars of the right type to be found. So you should either return null in both cases, or throw an exception in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the "cheapestCar" is initialized to be simply the first car in the array - without checking if that car is of the correct type (which in and of itself might be another problem).

So as a first step, get rid of that initialization:

```
Car cheapestCar = null;
```

Of course now the next line will fail because you cannot get the price of a non-existing car. Since the price is only used to determine potentially lower prices, it is safe to start with the highest price possible, in this case:

```
double price = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

The whole code would then be:

```
public static Car findCar (Car[] cars, String type) 
{ 
    if (cars.length == 0) 
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ("no cars"); 
 
    
    Car    cheapestCar = null; 
    double  price = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) 
        if (cars[i].getPrice() <= price && 
            cars[i].getType().equals(type)) 
        { 
            cheapestCar = cars[i]; 
            price = cheapestCar.getPrice (); 
            
        } 
    
    return cheapestCar;
}
```

Be careful, though, as any code *using* this function may not be able to handle a `null` return value (since currently it cannot be null).

I've also changed your price comparison from `<` to `<=` since the only car of the correct type could in theory have an infinite price as well. This might change your results if there is more than one "cheapest" car - your current function would return the *first* one found, my function with that changed comparison will return the *last* one found.

And as a general note, see [@konsolas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70669975/4616087) for a potentially more concise approach for the whole function and [Andy Turner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669908/how-can-i-fix-this-method-so-it-returns-null-if-the-car-type-is-not-found/70670092#comment124931083_70669908) for a slight (still existing) inconsistency regarding returning `null` vs throwing an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Java 8 Streams might help you do this more concisely.

```
public static Optional<Car> findCar (Car[] cars, String type) {
    return Arrays.stream(cars)
            .filter(car -> car.getType().equals(type))
            .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(car::getPrice));
}
```

It's usually better to return an `Optional<T>` instead of `null` as it helps ensure that users of the function don't forget about the case where no car exists.

Comment: Whilst true, this doesn't really help OP to understand how to fix the code in its current form.

Comment: This is dubious style advice. Methods like `java.util.Map`'s `get()` method does not and probably never will return `Optional` (as it wouldn't be backwards compatible), so doing this just splices your java codebase in twain: Some methods return `null` if not found, others return `Optional`. Best to use optional for what it was made for: Return types of terminal stream methods. It's also a non-answer in general, it just does a fly by 'hey, you should do this awesome thing!' instead of answering the question.